# Here Maps API JavaScript zoom into bounds with margin

Tags: javascript, here-api

I have several markers in a group and I want to zoom in, so they're all visible.

With version 3.0 of mapsjs I could do this:

```
var cameraData = map.getCameraDataForBounds(group.getBounds());
map.setZoom(cameraData.zoom - 0.5, true);
map.setCenter(cameraData.position, true);
```

With version 3.1 `getCameraDataForBounds` was removed and the [documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/markers/zoom-to-set-of-markers) tells me to do it this way:

```
map.getViewModel().setLookAtData({
  bounds: group.getBoundingBox()
}, true);
```

My problem is, that with the new way, the markers are very close to the edge. With the 3.0 way, I could add some margin by simply adjusting the zoom level. That doesn't seem possible with 3.1 since I can't seem to find a replacement for `getCameraDataForBounds`.

Zooming in and then back out, seems hacky and kills my animation. I tried widening the bounding box, but couldn't find a reliable way to do it.

Any advice on how to archive this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For this case you can simply use padding option when creating new Map instance:

```js
// assuming htmlElement and baseLayer exist
var map = new H.Map(htmlElement, baseLayer, {
  ...
  padding: {top: 50, left: 50, bottom: 50, right: 50}
});
```

or setting the padding on the fly:

```js
map.getViewPort().setPadding(50, 50, 50, 50)
```

Here is updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dvojka/shca38n6/) example.

See [Map#Options](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/api_reference/H.Map.html#.Options) or [ViewPort#setPadding](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/api_reference/H.map.ViewPort.html#setPadding) documentation for more details.